# AspectJ is not getting added to classpath with eclipse:eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, aspectj, maven-eclipse-plugin

I'm executing the following command,

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.6:clean \
    org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.6:eclipse
```

My all the dependencies are coming in classpath but AspectJ is not added to the classpath. I have them declared in pom.xml dependencies list

Where as it is working if I use some other version of eclipse plugin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without details about your maven-eclipse-plugin configuration but AFAIK, this is supposed to work. Maybe have a look at <strike>[MECLIPSE-544](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MECLIPSE-544)</strike> (and related issues). Basically, the issue suggest to set the following parameter (and value):

> In the configuration of the eclipse plugin add `<ajdtVersion>none</ajdtVersion>`. This should fix the problem.

Just out of curiosity, why are you using version 2.6?

Comment: Why I'm using 2.6 is because of known issue with 2.7 while using command "mvn eclipse:eclipse" is not generating classpath file and giving maven error (complaining about multiple entries of same kind like <Resources>..)

Answer (score 0):

Worked with the command

mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.6:clean org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.6:eclipse ***-Declipse.ajdtVersion=none***